# I may have a possible hacked Pokémon I got from trade, what should I do?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-sun-moon

I got a Shiny Groudon from trade AND it was not my fault. I am scared I think it's hacked and what if the Pokémon company finds out and banishes me?

I don't have game sync yet if that matters

Reasons why I think it's hacked:

1. It's shiny and I think I read something somewhere on another site that game mascot lengendaries were shiny locked.
2. It doesn't have that black cross thing near the shape things like all my other pokemons do.
3. When I read where it was from it said something about it coming from 
   Johto  region.

Is it hacked? What should I do?

Comment: I haven't played Pokémon in a while but I can see if I can research it a little bit more and try to find a way to help you (Transfer from RSE/HGSS and let them hold there specific orbs If they have pentagon its hacked I got a legit shiny kyogre from someone months ago and I sniped a shiny groudon from the GTS asking for a sudowoodo. At least they're not hacked since they got no ivs.) I hope this helped.

Comment: @rivermont-WillB. The latest games introduced a feature called wondertrade which let you trade a Pokemon with a random player from all over the world, so you receive a random Pokemon. And it's not so plausible that a player trades a legit shiny legendary for something random.

Comment: Undeleting this because it's a useful topic with a useful answer from @pinckerman. It was deleted automatically by the system 'Community' user after the OP user was removed.

Comment: It's reasonably easy to RNG a Groundon in SS, which would make it legit and look exactly this way (no cross/Pentagon, coming from Johto).

Answer (score 13):

First of all, if you don't use that Pokemon for online competitions you have nothing to fear.

1. Groudon is [shiny locked](http://serebii.net/games/shiny.shtml) only on ORAS, it could be legit if it comes from RSE or SS.
2. The black cross icon only means that the Pokemon is born or obtained in Alola, it doesn't mean that the Pokemon is hacked or something like that.
3. If it comes from Johto it could be legit, because you can catch a Groudon at [Embedded Tower](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Embedded_Tower).

If you don't want to have an hacked Pokemon just release it or trade it, it won't corrupt your game and you won't get banned only for that.